# PHP Paypal IPN, how to detect if subscribers change their email address

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Let's say a person changes their Paypal email address while still being subscribed to my service. How do I find out the user's new Paypal email address?

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could use the [Permissions API](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_Permissions.pdf), which is token based, so that you don't have to worry about this at all.

If you want to stick with using SUBJECT in your API requests (which is what I'm assuming you're doing now) you can have the user enter their PayPal Merchant Account ID instead of their PayPal email address, and use that for the SUBJECT value instead.  This value will never change, so if the user changes their email address it won't effect your solution.

Otherwise, you'll just have to keep an eye on your API logs and when they fail because of invalid credentials you can send a notification to that user that they need to update their email address on file with your app.

Comment: Ty so much andrew :)  i was thinking also of upating the ipn based on the subscriber's  paypal merchant id. Thanks for giving me more info also :). Ill check ot that token based when i have more time. Ty andrew